# JSONSchema Validation array items

Tags: json, jsonschema

I receive the following items in a JSON Array

```
{locations: [{locId: "1", locName: "ST1"}, {locId: "2", locName: "ST2"}, {locId: "3", locName: "ST3"}]}
```

My requirement is that inside `locations` the value for `locName` has to be one of `ST1`, `ST2`, or `ST3` (I don't care about `locId`).  How do I enforce this in the JSONSchema.  I saw you can use `array` but how do I specify that an object\item of the array should have one of the pre-defined values for a particular property.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`enum`](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/generic.html#enumerated-values) keyword to restrict the allowed values for a given property:

```
"locName": {
  "type": "string",
  "enum": ["ST1", "ST2", "ST3"]
}
```

---

Complete schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "locations": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "locId": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "locName": {
              "type": "string",
              "enum": ["ST1", "ST2", "ST3"]
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "locId",
            "locName"
          ]
        },        
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "locations"
  ]
}
```